# How do I create fractal index using tokudb engine?

Tags: mariadb, storage-engine, tokudb

I install MariaDb and configured it to use TokuDb Engine.

I need to use Fractal-Index Built-in on TokuDb Engine.

I have create my index as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE `table__name` ADD INDEX ( `column` );
```

I Do this following TokuDb wiki.

When i go on phpmyadmin as index type i see "BTREE".

Need I specify type on creation of index? What should I put as type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BTREE you see is just a label. If "show create table table_name;" displays engine=TokuDB then you can be sure that Fractal Tree indexes are in use.